# testing API extends REST_Controller codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest

Hi I want to create a Restful API in codeIgniter. 
So I started with testing chris kacer code (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver), but when i tape

```
localhost:9090/CodeIgniter/index.php/example/user/id/1
```

I always get this response:

```
{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}
```

I don't know where is the problem. i configured my routes.php

```
($route['default_controller'] = "example";)
```

and config.php

```
($config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:9090/CodeIgniter/';)
```

and it still not working. Can anyone help me please and thank you.

Comment: What is `user` is it a controller ? If yes you can access it via `http://localhost:9090/CodeIgniter/user/id/1`

Comment: Should the URL be (include the API directory); localhost:9090/CodeIgniter/index.php/api/example/user/id/1

Comment: nn example is the controller user_get is the function

Comment: write your example controller here

Comment: thank you the prob is resolved :)

Comment: Check my previous answer here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308898/rest-api-codeigniter/28314930#28314930][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308898/rest-api-codeigniter/28314930#28314930

Answer (score 1):

When working with rest_codeighniter api the controller logic is kinda different in the sense that ur "methods/public functions" in the ur controller class(the one that extends the rest_controller) are created by combining the RESOURCE name and the HTTP method(e.g get,post,put etc). therefore if ur resource name is "user" and u want to make a "get" http call, ur method/function would be declared as "public function user_get(){ //ur code here } " .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't included the REST library class file. If that's the case then adding the lines below should resolve your error,

```
// including rest api class
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

// use namespace
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
```